# Cannot find file on shared drive

Tags: c#, winforms, file, server, client

We have a C# WinForms application that is run on the client. The application downloads a file from an FTP, saves it on a shared drive (hosted on the server) and the server will then run some code to decrypt the file and post the decrypted file back to the shared drive, to the same location as the encrypted file, under a different file name. When this is completed, the execution is then passed back to the client and it attempts to check if the decrypted file exists. It then throws an exception because the file cannot be found.

Client code:

```
protected void DecryptFile(string aEncryptedFilePath, string aDecryptedFilePath)
{
  AppController.Task.SystemTaskManager.ExecuteTask(new TaskRequest(TaskPgpFileDecrypt.TaskId, aEncryptedFilePath, aDecryptedFilePath));

  if (!File.Exists(aDecryptedFilePath)
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist"); // Exception thrown here
}
```

Server code:

```
public TaskResponse Execute(string aSourceFilePath, string aDestinationFilePath)
{
  // Decryption Code

  if (!File.Exists(DestinationFilePath))
    throw new ApplicationException($"Could not {ActionDescription} file {SourceFilePath}. Expected output file {DestinationFilePath} is missing.");

  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(DestinationFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    fileStream.Flush(true);

  return new TaskResponse();
}
```

I've simplified it as best as I can but you can see that the client passes in an `aEncryptedFilePath` and what it expects to be the `aDecrypedFilePath` and the server code will decrypt the encrytped file and store on the path stored in`aDestinationFilePath`.

Now in the server code, you can also see that we check if the file exists and if it doesn't, the server will throw an exception. But here's the kicker. The server's file exists check returns true and continues the execution. It's only when we get to the client side code does the `File.Exist` check fail! We've tried flushing the buffer to ensure that the file is written to the disk but this doesn't help at all.

Another bit of useful information is that I can verify that the file exists because if I watch the folder where the file is created, I can see that it's created. However, if I click the file immediately after it shows up I get this warning from windows:

[image]

If I close the warning and wait a second or two, I am then able to open the file.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Disk latency???

Comment: But then why would it show that the file exists on the server?

Comment: Perhaps there is a gap between the directory entry appearing and the file actually being available?

Comment: Please can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

The Task class is an asynchronous operation. Based on the code here you are firing the decrypt command and then immediately checking to see if the file exists after you have issues the command to decrypt it. Because this is going to take some server cycles to complete you will need to wait for the task to complete before you access the file.

There is a really good MSDN doc that shows how to wait for a task to complete before continuing the code execution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8#WaitingForOne

Comment: With that being said though... if you are firing the task just to communicate with another application then you might be running into some other communication complexity. So the task will fire, communicate with the server and then the server will start to decrypt... before the server can finish the main app is already checking to see if the decrypted file exists. If that is the case you will need to put some logic in place to keep track of the progress server and client side and they will need to be coupled.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. It is not a Task class, we just have our own 'Tasks'. They are not asynchronous